# Heap out of memory in angular4 while ng build --prod

Tags: angular

I am getting an heap out of memory error while ng build --prod ,Is there any work around. its building fine when --aot=false.

Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: `node --max_old_space_size=4096`

Comment: Why increase the ram is a solution? Also this happen in angular 12 and 13 versions

Answer (score 36):

Try running build script in package json by the following script:

```
"scripts": {
   "build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"
}
```

**[`Reference`](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1652)**

Answer (score 23):

Here are the steps i have done to fix the issue based on above post and its worked well for me.

Step-1

Open package.json

Add this code under scripts

"build-prod": "node --max_old_space_size=5048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod"

[image]

Step-2

Open terminal and run execute this code "npm run build-prod"

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: So only improvement could be to use `./node_modules/.bin/ng` instead of `./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng`. So if the path changes anytime, you use the symlink.

Answer (score 23):

My team was facing the same issue and this is how we resolved.

While building the project instead of `ng build --prod` use this

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

OR
 Just add above string in your **package.json** file like this and to build use just **`npm run prod`**,

```
    {
  "name": "Deva_Application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "prod": "node --max_old_space_size=64384  ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --build-optimizer --output-hashing=none",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
...
}
```

In case of large project increase the --max_old_space_size to 16384 to 64384.

Answer (score 11):

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096
```

Comment: using this method causes less issues during CI/CD

Comment: For Windows, in the prompt:
set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096

Answer (score 0):

While upping the heap size can for sure resolve this issue,
I also recommend checking your supported browsers, see 'https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist'

When my app stopped building with 12gb I looked into other solutions and for me I was able to limit to browsers we actually support and I reduced heap size to 8gb (I suspect I could go lower but didn't bother testing)

My config now

```
# Browsers that we support
# Take caution when expanding out this list, as builds will require more ram '--max_old_space_size'

last 2 Chrome versions,
last 2 FireFox versions,
last 2 Edge versions,
last 2 Safari versions
last 2 Opera versions
```