# ERR! NG_BUILD FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: angular, npm

I am getting javascript out of memory as stated below while I do build my angular application

```
@bb-cli/bb-ang] ERR! NG_BUILD FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

For that I tried using set NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=8192 but it keeps appearing randomly.

I am running with angular6 application.

Comment: look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46807355/heap-out-of-memory-in-angular4-while-ng-build-prod) I hope it solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in your project folder
`node --max_old_space_size=8000 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve  --prod --port=4202`

Comment: If you are working with a Node Version >= 8, this will absolutely work